# A payment method in sign up feature

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an music application that charges user per songs are played. I have an a registration functionality that helps user to sign up and register their card with some files: name or card, card number, expire date etc.

I am concerning if getting card info will be rejected by Apple. My assumption is the songs I buy are approved by Apple.

I am really appreciated with any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle branded credit cards from the major card schemes (Including Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover, and JCB) your system/backend should be **PCI DSS compliance** (The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard), Which is a proprietary information security standard to ensure security of the stored/transmitted card information over the open network. Of course Apple will reject your app if you are not PCI compliance. This is an expensive process and it needs constant supervision and maintenance of the backend server. Still if you wish to handle your customers' cards by yourself, [Get started from here.](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/why_security_matters)

There are few workarounds. You can simply use third party service providers such as [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/) or [Zooz payments](http://zooz.com/) instead of handling customer card information by your own.

Also you can go for [Apple in-app purchase](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) which is the native mechanism/framework for payments handling. Infact i recommend to go with [Apple in-app purchase](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) so you don't have to worry about any card information handling and there is really less work to implement.

All the above payment options i mentioned here are supporting Subscriptions, One time payments, etc...